# Problem in Soft Deleting child entity in Spring Boot in @OneToMany relation set null id to referance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement soft delete between a parent and child entity when ı implement bidirectional it works as ı want but when ı implement unidirectional it sets a null id reference.

### User.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE user SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ? " )
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class User extends AbstractBaseModel {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    .
    .
    .
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tasks> tasks;

}
```

### Task.java

there are bi-direction references between the user and the task

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "task")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE task SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ? " )
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class Task extends AbstractBaseModel {
    private String taskName;
    private String lastState;
    .
    .
    .
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<TaskHistory> taskHistory;

}
```

### TaskHistory.java

there is no reference here there is a unidirectional reference   between  task and task history

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "task_history")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE task_history SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ? " )
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class TaskHistory extends AbstractBaseModel {
    private String state;
    .
    .
    .

}
```

when ı delete a user with JPA like the one below

```
userRepository.deleteById(id);
```

that's run four query

```
Hibernate: update task_history set task_id=null where task_id=? and ((is_deleted = false) )
Hibernate: UPDATE task_history SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ?
Hibernate: UPDATE task SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ?
Hibernate: UPDATE user SET is_deleted = true WHERE id = ? and version = ?
```

ı don't want the first query. when that set task_id=null ı can not return the first situation

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the code below
@JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false)
when ı delete user hibernate can not set null